# Exclude already sent subscribers from an automation

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio

I have an automation set up where the file drops from an FTP server every morning! We have a query to identify subscribers based on that file drop. And then an email is sent every day!
All good until here, but the file drop has multiple subscribers repeated from previous sends. What is the best way to avoid sending the email to the same subscriber over and over again? Should this be done through a query or a script in the email?

Thanks

Comment: what platform sends the email? salesforce? Salesforce apex? salesforce workflow? you could enhance the logic that sends the email by adding a statement after the email sends successfully, that could log/persist the fileId+subscriberId into a datastore, then you would just check that store before sending emails to help avoid sending the fileId more than once to any given subscriber. You could use a setup/declarative “unique” text field and flow to maintain such a combokey, or you could code the logic. Just make the email routine honor it. Thanks in advance for the information.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is Marketing Cloud, the easiest way to deal with is to use Journey Builder to send the email. You can then specify the re-entry criteria so that once a contact has entered the journey, they cannot re-enter at a later date. You can then be sure that only new contacts in your data extension get sent the email.

More information: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_journey_settings.htm&r=https:%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=5